# fread() crash when reading the small txt file

Tags: r, fread

When I use `fread` from `data.table` package to read the [data from](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vH4BPt5EpVa1JreVl6V3lFWUk/view?usp=sharing), R crashes with a segfault. How can I investigate this further? To reproduce just download the file and type :

```
library(data.table)
fread("SH600212.txt") # or fread("SH600212.txt", verbose=TRUE)
```

But when I add or delete a char at the end of file, it works OK!

Comment: It works for me. R v3.1.2 64bit, Linux, data.table v1.9.6

Comment: Works also for me. Please provide more information, such as `sessionInfo()` (or `devtools::session_info()` if `devtools` is installed).

Comment: Reproducible on my mac on v1.9.6/1.9.7, thanks. Will have a look at it.

Comment: my computer envirment: R v3.1.1 64bit, Win7, data.table v1.96.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got to the bottom of this one, [#1464](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1464).

The file size of SH600212.txt is an exact multiple of 4096, and, the last row is not finished with a newline. Page issues can vary between architectures which explains why it worked for some. `echo >> SH600212.txt` would fix it by appending the final newline as a workaround.

Now fixed in v1.10.5.